# SMTP:Sending an Email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

i want to send an email through SMTP using C# and ASP.NET but the main thing is that i want to change or hide From Address, kindly help me to solve this problm

Comment: Could you share the code you have written?

Comment: Who you can send `from` will depend on what your SMTP allows you to do (sometimes it must be same domain, or the same user in the credentials, or sometimes no restrictions). You cannot hide `from`.

Comment: Mike is right on that one, gmail, for instance;does not let you fake a sender's address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

Set from@email to whatever you like.

```
var client = new SmtpClient("yoursmptserver.com")
{
   Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@email", "pass"),
};

client.Send("from@email", "to@email", "subject", "body");
```

Oh and btw, there is no way to hide the sender.

However you can use:

```
var from = new MailAddress("from@email", "DisplayName");
```

to set a display name...

Comment: :) I get pissed when I see people asking stupid questions here on SO, but I get pissed even more when I see people writing negative comments, if you don't like it, or someone pissed in your coffee, don't bother commenting, right? :)